# R: apply/ lapply: How to Create a bar chart if all entries in on column are 1's?

Tags: r, bar-chart, apply, lapply

imagine, you have the following data set:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  Wine    Beer    Water   Age Gender
1   0   1   0   20  Male
2   1   0   1   38  Female
3   0   0   1   32  Female
4   1   0   1   30  Male
5   1   1   1   30  Male
6   1   1   1   26  Female
7   0   1   1   36  Female
8   0   1   1   29  Male
9   0   1   1   33  Female
10  0   1   1   20  Female"))
```

Further, imagine you want to compile summary tables that print out the frequencies of those that drink wine, beer, water.

I solved it that way.

```
con<-apply(df[,c(2:4)], 2, table)
con_P<-prop.table(con,2)
```

This allows me to complete my ultimate goal of compiling a bar chart in the way I want it:

```
barplot(con_P)
```

It works perfectly. No problem. Now, let us tweak the data set as follows: We set all entries for water to 1.

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  Wine    Beer    Water   Age Gender
1   0   1   1   20  Male
2   1   0   1   38  Female
3   0   0   1   32  Female
4   1   0   1   30  Male
5   1   1   1   30  Male
6   1   1   1   26  Female
7   0   1   1   36  Female
8   0   1   1   29  Male
9   0   1   1   33  Female
10  0   1   1   20  Female"))
```

If I now run the following commands:

```
con<-apply(df[,c(2:4)], 2, table)
con_P<-prop.table(con,2)
```

it gives me the following error message after the second line: `Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array!`

Through another question here on this forum, I learned that the following will help me to overcome this issue:

```
con_P <- lapply(con, function(x) x/sum(x))
```

However, if I now run

```
barplot(con_P)
```

R does not create a barplot: `Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I assume it is because it is no array!

My question is what to do now (how would I transform `con_P` in th second example into an array?). Secondly, how can I make the entire step of creating prop.tables and then a bar chart more efficient? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can by converting the columns to `factor` with `levels` specified.  In the second example, as the columns have 0 and 1 values in the 2nd and 3rd, we use the `levels` as `0:1`, then get the `table` and convert to proportion with `prop.table`. and do the `barplot`

```
 barplot(prop.table(sapply(df[2:4], 
         function(x) table(factor(x, levels=0:1))),2))
```

Comment: ! I still need to digest what you have proposed but it works just fine! I am intrigued to ask what is about factors that they don't cause this problem. Thanks for the quick reply through!

Comment: @DomB By converting to `factor` with `levels` specified, the `table` output gives the frequency of `0` for the missing value 0 in the column 4, and when the lengths are same across the `list`, the `sapply` output will be converted to `matrix`.  Otherwise, it will still be a `list`.

Comment: ! Thanks for that. I am still not entirely sure of what is happening. But this is now up to me to figure that out!

Answer (score 1):

Reproducing your data:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  Wine    Beer    Water   Age Gender
1   0   1   1   20  Male
2   1   0   1   38  Female
3   0   0   1   32  Female
4   1   0   1   30  Male
5   1   1   1   30  Male
6   1   1   1   26  Female
7   0   1   1   36  Female
8   0   1   1   29  Male
9   0   1   1   33  Female
10  0   1   1   20  Female"))

con <-lapply(df[,c(2:4)], table)
con_P <- lapply(con, function(x) x/sum(x))
```

You can use `reshape2` to melt the data:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(con_P)
```

Now, if you want to use `gpplot2` you can use `df` to plot the bar plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = L1, y = value, fill = factor(Var1) )) + 
  geom_bar(stat= "identity") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want to use `barplot` you can reshape the `data.frame` into an `array`:

```
array <- acast( df, Var1~L1)
array[is.na(array)] <- 0
barplot(array)
```

[image]

Comment: ! Thanks for that! More stuff to digest!